# local PHP file is downloading instead of opening in browser

Tags: php, google-chrome, download

First let me state that I am NOT running a web server.

I am running on Windows 7 64-bit.  When I open a php file the browser is downloading it instead of showing it as text.  I am using Notepad++ to "Launch in Chrome" and it shows up in the address bar correctly but is downloading to my download directory.   Just a couple of days ago this was working fine and displaying the text of the php file.

I know you need a web server with PHP installed to get the file to render correctly but that is not what I'm trying to do.  I simply want it to display the php file as text.  Then I change the file:/// portion of the URL to localhost and it works.

Comment: You probably installed software that took over the *.php file extension.

Comment: Works fine in Chrome 28. But still, "why would you want this"?

Comment: localhost won't work unless you have it defined in host file or a local webserver. It works fine for me in Chrome.

Comment: I am going through a video training class for PHP.  The instructions have you using NotePad++.  In the Run menu of NotePad++, you can chose "Launch in Chrome" and the PHP file loaded in the editor should launch in chrome as text use the file:/// prefix.  It used to do that just fine.  A couple of days ago, it stop doing it and started downloading the file instead.  So I am trying to figure out why it's downloading the PHP file which is local to my hard drive to my download directory instead of just display it.

Answer (score -1):

That's because php is unlike html a server based programming language, it cannot be run on the computer without a server, and i assume you don't know what I am talking about, but here is how you should do it: -

1. Download Xamp or Wamp from the internet: - here is a link for you:-
   http://xampp.en.softonic.com/
2. Follow this video in order to install it : - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ev9RAsvFfoc
3. Follow this video in order to start running php files through the installed XAMP: -
   http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ImZEwrHohRg

Comment: You must not have read my posting.  I already have WAMP installed and working.  But when I launch in Chrome from NotePad++ it should launch in the browser and display as text.  I then remove the file:/// piece of the URL and substitute "localhost" to get it to render.  I'm just trying to display the file in the browser before I edit the URL to render the file.

Comment: I have read what you've said but I didn't realise that your problem is still going on with WAMP.. have you tried opening the browser then accessing the file from the local host? like localhost/xamp/htdocs/etc?

And check if the file format is .php just in case since i still don't have a full visual on the problem and please add screenshots to the problem if it still exists

Answer (score -1):

From what i have understood you dont need to render php but just open php in text format like it would open in notepad++. Earlier it did but now it is rendering the php file than just the text.
try using different browsers!!! Firefox or opera should help you with that. You can get the url in these or any browsers as well